# How to create a button style (with example) in HTML5/ CSS3?

Tags: html, css

[Example](http://themeforest.net/item/stylico-dj-template/full_screen_preview/476481)

In this website the left corner there is a list of buttons "Home , biography, Discography..."

When the user select different page , the "blue pointer" move along with the user select item.

I would like to know how to implement it?

And I would like to do slightly different with this example.
Currently I have a menu in horizontal form

eg.

Item A | Item B | Item C | Item D

^

How to make the pointer "^" move along and go to the item that user selected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot JQuery plugins for that.

See this:

[Site link](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-menu.html)

This seems like a good solution:

[Example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/28/awesome-cufonized-fly-out-menu/)

Demo:
[Demo](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CufonizedFlyOutMenu/)